# Eclipse Formatter Options for '.' Alignment (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like Eclipse to format some code which calls a builder as follows:

```
final Item item = new Item.Builder()
                          .name("something")
                          .field("a value")
                          .build();
```

i.e. aligning on the '.' character from the first line.  I can manually convince Eclipse to do this by aligning the second line (the .name("something")) by hand, but any auto-formatting destroys this.

I've played around with all of the various formatting options that I can find in Eclipse and none of them seem to do what I want.  Any ideas on if there are format options to lay out the code in this way?

Comment: personally I think this is a bad way to format code. If you rename item to carPart then your formatting will be off or you'll have to touch all following lines. If you are in a team of ppl and you use SCM than this will be an ugly check in, because you touched lines irrelevant to your actual change, the rename. Not a problem in your pet project. A big problem when trying to pinpoint the changes after a production issue when the boss is breathing down your neck.

Comment: Well any change of length of a line could cause knock-on effects to subsequent lines if you don't allow lines to have unlimited length so I don't see how this is a special case.  And if you're refactoring in the way that you say then you should do it as a separate commit so that it's separate from any other code changes.

Answer (score 5):

Aligning exactly at the dot position is not possible, but the linebreaks for each method call can be done automatically. I've created this output

```
void format() {
    Test test = new Test()
            .a()        // this call can also be configured to be one line above
            .b()
            .c();
}
```

by selecting the *Line Wrapping* tab in the formatter settings, selecting *Function Calls, Qualified invocations*, switching the *Line wrapping policy* in the combo box to **Wrap all elements, every element on a new line** and finally checking the checkbox *Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width*.

You can get the first method call into the first line by selecting the "...except first element" policy instead.

Comment: can you try it with this:     private static String getErrorMessage(final MyFile file) {
        return new StringBuilder(ERROR_MESSAGE).append(" ").append(
                file.getDataType()).append(" ").append(FILE_NAME).append(
                file.getFileNameNoPathNoSuffix()).toString();
    }
and I think you will see that the result is really ugly - at least with Eclipse Luna. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new formater:

`Properties -> Formater -> Configure Workspace Settings -> New`

then on the tab `Off/On Tags` set `Enable Off/On tags`

And then just surround your code like this:

```
/* @formatter:off */
final Item item = new Item.Builder()
                          .name("something")
                          .field("a value")
                          .build();
/* @formatter:on */
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately  I have a large amount of code which is badly formatted and I want Eclipse to format it as per the standards in the question rather than have to carry it out manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can achieve this by using 'jalopy'.  There is a plugin for Maven, if you use Maven.

In case, you would like to use jalopy then, the setting that you would be interested is `<methodCallChain>` in the `alignment` element whose value you should set to `true`.

Edited: [maven jalopy plugin](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http://mojo.codehaus.org/jalopy-maven-plugin/&ei=rioYUYW1Koub1AXtsIGgAg&usg=AFQjCNEdjx-6tB8jjXa4BFK6CoE_yvrd_w&sig2=r2_-avFL2VIkOvARtXY_JA).  Make sure you target the `clean` phase and use the goal `format`